# Physics informed neural network using tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network

Using PINN I'm trying to solve this equation:
C*T'+K*T=Q'

T is the rod temperature
C Heat capacity matrix
K Heat conductivity matrix

K and C are given 51*51 diagonal matrices and Q' is 15193*51 I also have temperature data which is also of size 15193 since the temperature is measured over 51 nodes all the 60 second.

The input of my neural network is time and the output is the temperature in each node of the 51.
when trying to compute the physical loss. I get an error.

This my code

```
import os 
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL']='2'
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Constants
t0 = 0
dt = 60
t_end = 15193 * dt

# Load data
C = np.genfromtxt("C_th.txt", dtype=float, delimiter=",")
K = np.genfromtxt("K_th.txt", dtype=float, delimiter=",")
Q_prime = np.genfromtxt("thermal_loads.txt", dtype=float, skip_header=1, delimiter=",")[:15193]
temperatures = np.genfromtxt("temperature_rod.txt", dtype=float, skip_header=1, delimiter=",")[:15193]

# Convert to TensorFlow tensors and appropriate dtypes
C = tf.cast(C, tf.float32)
K = tf.cast(K, tf.float32)
Q_prime = tf.cast(Q_prime, tf.float32)
temperatures = tf.cast(temperatures, tf.float32)

# Neural Network Model
class PINNModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(PINNModel, self).__init__()
        self.dense_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(20, activation=tf.nn.tanh)
        self.dense_2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(20, activation=tf.nn.tanh)
        self.dense_3 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(20, activation=tf.nn.tanh)
        self.output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(51, activation=None)

    def call(self, inputs):
        x = self.dense_1(inputs)
        x = self.dense_2(x)
        x = self.dense_3(x)
        return self.output_layer(x)

# Preparing the data
time_inputs = np.arange(t0, t_end, dt)
time_inputs = tf.reshape(tf.cast(time_inputs, dtype=tf.float32), (-1, 1))  # Convert to column vector
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((time_inputs, temperatures)).batch(32)

# Define the model and optimizer
model = PINNModel()
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)

# Loss functions
def data_loss(predictions, true_temperatures):
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(predictions - true_temperatures))

def physics_loss(time_inputs, predictions, C, K, Q_prime):
    with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
        tape.watch(time_inputs)
        dT_dt = tape.gradient(predictions, time_inputs)
    C_dT_dt = C @ dT_dt
    KT = K @ predictions
    residuals = C_dT_dt + KT - Q_prime
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(residuals))


def combined_loss(time_inputs, true_temperatures, predictions, C, K, Q_prime):
    return data_loss(predictions, true_temperatures) + physics_loss(time_inputs, predictions, C, K, Q_prime)

predictions = model(time_inputs)
print("predictions====================", predictions, tf.shape(predictions))
print("time===============", time_inputs, tf.shape(time_inputs))

print(physics_loss(time_inputs, predictions, C, K, Q_prime))
```

the error:
ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (None) with an unsupported type (<class 'NoneType'>) to a Tensor.

Comment: Which line of code is pointed by the error? Also in your equation, why are C and K not constants (floats)? Is your rod special? A complete setup of the problem would help to solve your issue.

Comment: Please paste the entire error trace. We need to know which variable is `None`. A wild guess is that you need to check the PDE loss. Just pass some numbers to the PDE and check the output dimension of the tensor.